# Associate a integer (literal) with functions, let caller query number of FLOPs

Tags: c++

I work on a high performance code where we have BLAS functions, stencil operators and iterative solvers. For performance measurement, we use our hand-calculated number of “useful” flops and divide by the time the algorithm needed. This gives use the “useful” performance.

The stencils are classes, so I could add a `virtual int get_flops() const` member function. In the iterative solvers I would just add up the flops from the various stencil calls.

The BLAS routines are functions, however. They are of like `void copyVector(V a, const V b)`. I'd like to associate the integer `0` to this function. Using the return value seems like a quick fix, but I might want to add another annotation later on.

One option would be turning those into singleton classes with an `operator()`, but this feels like a violation of the open-closed principle (OCP). Is there something like type traits that I can do for functions?

Comment: You can use function names as non-type template parameters. That won't work for function templates though.

Comment: @Quentin it would if you won't ommit the template parameter(s) :)

Comment: @W.F. you cannot partially specialize them to treat a function template as a whole, is what I meant :p

Comment: @Quentin oh,  yep that's still impossible in c++ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Radosław Cybulski's answer, I have expanded this to a full working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename Annotation>
class FunctionAnnotation {
  public:
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    Annotation get(R (*func)(Args...)) {
        return map_.at(strip(func));
    }

    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    void set(R (*func)(Args...), Annotation annotation) {
        map_[strip(func)] = annotation;
    }

  private:
    // Basic function pointer type.
    typedef void (*VoidFunc)();

    // Type stripping function that will take a function pointer and return a
    // function with the wrong but unified type.
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    VoidFunc strip(R (*func)(Args...)) {
        return reinterpret_cast<VoidFunc>(func);
    }

    // The map with annotation values.
    std::unordered_map<VoidFunc, Annotation> map_;
};

FunctionAnnotation<int> flop_map;

// Some example functions.
void blas_routine(double *const dest, double const *const src) {}
void other(int a, int b) {}

int main() {
    // Populate that map.
    flop_map.set(blas_routine, 0);
    flop_map.set(other, 4);

    // Later on use that.
    std::cout << flop_map.get(blas_routine) << std::endl;
    std::cout << flop_map.get(other) << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles cleanly with GCC in C++11 and C++14 modes. The output is, as expected:

```
0
4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something more like:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct dummy { };

template <class T>
struct flop_map {
    static int value;
};

template <class T>
int flop_map<T>::value;

#define FOO_ID(foo) std::integral_constant<decltype(&foo), &foo>

void blas_routine(double *const, double const *const) {}
void other(int, int) {}

int main() {
    flop_map<FOO_ID(blas_routine)>::value = 0;
    flop_map<FOO_ID(other)>::value        = 4;

    std::cout << flop_map<FOO_ID(blas_routine)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << flop_map<FOO_ID(other)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uq6Wz207uw7aMu2R)

Comment: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

typeid is not guaranteed to return the same object. I'd expect this code to produce two entries for the same function, when called from - for example - two dll's. At minimum you should use std::type_index.

Also i dont like the solution - you produce more types and force compiler to produce rtti for them, which takes memory.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski you had a good point there with rtti there. I've revised my answer this should be free of this kind of drawbacks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create global unordered_map and associate integer with function pointer. Something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<void(*)(void), int> tmp;
```

As far as i remember standard guarantees, that function pointers for all types have the same size and since you just use function pointer to index into map, you can cast any function pointer (not pointer to member tho) to void (*)(void) and set / retrieve from unordered_map.

Comment: They don't have to be `constexpr`, I just wrote that to signal that I know the values at compile time, they are just integer literals.

Comment: That does not seem to work, `ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::unordered_map<void (*)(), int>' and 'void(double*, const double*)')` and `conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
function-traits.cpp:25:21: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(double*, const double*)' to 'std::unordered_map<void (*)(), int>::key_type {aka void (*)()}' [-fpermissive]`. I would need something that type-erases the function arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the explicit cast. The need of an `reinterpret_cast` makes this feel dangerous. See my answer for a working version with a class that can hold arbitrary annotations for arbitrary functions. Is what what you had in mind?